# cakephp 2.x plugin not working in cakephp 3.x

Tags: plugins, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

i have develope one plugin in cakephp 2.x and its working fine i am managing basic configuration for y website for this i have make the following things and below is the code

in AppController

```
public $uses = array(
    'Configuration.Configuration',
); 

public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Configuration->load();

}
```

after that in the my plugin's model i have create the function

```
function load(){
    $settings = $this->find('all');
    foreach ($settings as $variable){
      Configure::write("{$variable['Configuration']['name']}",$variable['Configuration']['value']);
    }
}
```

then in my main admin login file i a using configuration

```
<?php 

    echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image(Configure::read('Site.logo'),array('alt' => 'logo','title'=>Configure::read('Site.title'),'style'=>'max-width:148px;max-height:33px;')),array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login','plugin'=>false), array('escape'=>false));

?>
```

its working fine but when i am using this process with cakephp 3.x its whoing the error

```
Error: Class 'Configure' not found
File E:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\src\Template\Layout\login.ctp
Line: 67
```

plesae tell me how can i solve this and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CakePHP 3 comes with many drastic changes in file structuare and name space usage. so Any plugin developed in 2.x will not work in 3.x

For that you must have to refer migration guide document.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html

Also CakePHP provides upgrade tool which will be help to you.
https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade

Thanks

Comment: i checked it but i dont know how to make work  $this->Configuration->load(); function which is in cake 2.x  beforefilter in app folder so that i can call plugins model function in main sitesd app controller and use that data in complete site